# Prove that $\int_0^1 g \, dx = \frac{1}{2}$.

Tags: real-analysis, riemann-integration

> Prove that if $g(x):=0$ for $0 \le x \le \frac{1}{2}$ and $g(x):=1$ for $\frac{1}{2}<x\le 1$, then we have $\int_0^1 g \, dx= \frac{1}{2}$.

I know that I must define a partition $P= \{I_1, I_2, \dots, I_n \}$ of $[0,1]$ and then somehow show that $L(f)=U(f) = \frac{1}{2}$.

I am, however not sure how to do this exactly. Can somebody please help me? I am self-studying this section so I do not have anybody helping me with this.

Comment: Can you use the fact that $\int_0^1 gdx = \int_0^{1/2}gdx + \int_{1/2}^1gdx$?

Comment: @joriki - Apologies. It should be $g(x):=1$ for $\frac{1}{2} < x \le 1$. I typed the question straight out of a textbook (they didn't put $dx$ in the book) :). But I do agree that it needs to be there :)

Comment: Is there any difference between $:=$ and $=$ in your case? It is just to show that it is defining the function of $g$ or it means something else.

Comment: @Majid , not that I can notice :). I just think they used $:=$ for $g$ to say that "we define $g$ to be this ... " :)

Comment: So, you may say that this integral is equal to the area of a rectangle of size $1\times 1/2$, and so it is equal to $1/2$. Don't you?

Comment: Are we avoiding the use of the FToC here?

Comment: It is such a simple integration that one wonders what definition of integral or what collection of "known properties" of the integral you are allowed to use here.  Can you at least specify the calculus textbook you are "self-studying"?

Comment: @hardmath . This was an exercise in "Introduction to Real Analysis, R.G. Bartle and D.R. Sherbert, 2nd Edition". Section 7.1 Exercise 3(a).

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Try looking at partitions of the form $\{0,\frac12, \frac12+\epsilon,1\}$ where $\epsilon$ takes on small (less than $\frac12$) positive values.